# Using PHP if/then with echo on MyBB

Tags: php, echo, mybb, conditional-statements

I've searched far and wide for this and can't find a solution.

Basically, if it's a certain day of the month I'd like a certain word displayed on the front of MyBB board. I would like it to say "Spring" between the 1st and 8th of the month, "Summer" the 9th-17th, etc. I've figured out how to do this - but I can't get it to "Echo." Essentially, the way myBB is set up I've put the code on the Index.php file. I need it to echo as $season . Every thing I try just gives me if/then error statements. I'm not well versed enough to figure it out.

```
$d = date('d');
if ($d=="01")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="02")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="03, birth")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="04, birth")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="05, birth")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="06, birth")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="07, birth")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="08")
  echo "Spring"; 
if ($d=="09")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="10")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="11")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="12")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="13")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="14")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="15")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="16")
  echo "Summer"; 
if ($d=="17")
  echo "Autumn"; 
if ($d=="18")
  echo "Autumn"; 
if ($d=="19, breed")
  echo "Autumn"; 
if ($d=="20, breed")
  echo "Autumn"; 
if ($d=="21, breed")
  echo "Autumn"; 
if ($d=="22, breed")
  echo "Autumn"; 
if ($d=="23, breed")
  echo "Autumn"; 
if ($d=="24")
  echo "Winter"; 
if ($d=="25")
  echo "Winter"; 
if ($d=="26")
  echo "Winter"; 
if ($d=="27")
  echo "Winter"; 
if ($d=="28")
  echo "Winter"; 
if ($d=="29")
  echo "Winter"; 
if ($d=="30")
  echo "Winter"; 
if ($d=="31")
  echo "Winter";
```

If there's a way to have this correspond to $season so when I insert that variable into the layout it echos the above, that'd be amazing!

EDIT - what if I did something like this?

```
    $d = date('d');
$season = '';

If ($d == '01') {
    $season = 'Spring';
} If ($d == '02') {
    $season = 'Spring';
} If ($d == '28') {
    $season = 'Winter';
}
```

And then in the body have $season ? This way, on the 1st day of the month $season would say "Spring", and on the 28th day of the month $season would say "Winter" ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

RTM: http://php.net/date

The `d` format returns the day of the month in `01` through `31` format. It will **NEVER** return `04, birth`.

And in technical terms, your repeated if() tests are incredibly inefficient. Why not test RANGES of numbers?

```
$d = date('j'); // simple integer: 1 -> 31, no leading zeroes

if (($d >= 1) && ($d <= 4)) {
   echo 'Spring';
else if (($d >= 5) && ($d <= 7)) {
   echo 'Summer';
etc...
```

Comment: I wasn't aware I could do ranges, which would be very easy. However, this does not solve my original problem - I need this to echo on the main page. Essentially, I know what to put in the "header" for the code to work, I now need what to put in the "body" for the code to work. Also, when I do it the way you described, I get this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/equinus/public_html/beqanna/forum/index.php on line 397"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if()....
     else if()...
```

statements or your program will check  **ALL** the conditions even if it hits the first if and prints it.